# Sobrescrever property() na classe filha

Tags: python, python-3.x, descriptors

A alguns dias atrás fiz uma pergunta semelhante à essa, porém, o método empregado na criação da `property` era via decorators (`@property` e `@name.setter`). Aqui estou criando a `property` via função `property()`:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Person(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, name, telephone):
        self.name = name
        self.telephone = telephone

    def get_name(self) -> str:
        return self.__name

    def set_name(self, value: str):
        self.__name = value

    name = property(fget=get_name, fset=set_name)

class Employee(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, telephone, email):
        super().__init__(name, telephone)
        self.email = email
```

Na teoria sei o que precisa ser feito,o atributo `name.fset` da classe `Person` terá que apontar para uma versão modificada da função `set_name`, porém não sei como seria isso na prática. Fiz algumas tentativas mas não funcionou:

```
class Employee(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, telephone, email):
        super().__init__(name, telephone)
        self.email = email

    def set_name(self, value):
        super().set_name('override')

    super(self.__class__, self.__class__).name.fset = set_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso, o importante é entender em que momento cada uma das chamadas é feita, e como tudo é montado junto.

**Não tente usar `__` para variáveis privadas**

Antes de abordar o ponto central no entanto, chamo a atenção pra uma coisa - o uso de `__`, dois underscores, como prefixo de um nome numa classe, causa um "name mangling" do nome, mas isso não é o mesmo que uma "variável privada".  Documentação mais antiga do Python (coisas com mais de 10 anos) tendem a dizer que o uso de dois underscores é o mesmo que uma variável "privada" como existe no Java ou em outras linguagens - isso não é verdade - em Python não há o conceito de variáveis privadas, exceto a indicação de que um atributo não deve ser modificado por usuários da classe - e isso é simplesmente uma convenção. Dois `__` ativam um mecanismo de modificação do nome da variável em tempo de compilação (sim, código Python é compilado apesar desse passo ser transparente para o desenvolvedor). Nesse caso específico, isso só vai fazer com que a sua variável `self.__name` na classe herdada seja *diferente* da variável `self.__name` na classe mãe - se você mantivesse seu código e mudasse só o setter, o getter iria tentar ler uma variável que não existe.

**O que é um objeto retornado por `property`**

Em Python, a função embutida "property" retorna um objeto que é um *descriptor*. Isso é um objeto que implementa um método dentre `__get__`, `__set__` ou `__delete__` - e são esses métodos num objeto que seja um atributo de classe que fazem com que a manipulação do mesmo atributo *na instância* siga regras diferentes das de atributos normais. Na prática, o property é apenas uma forma "arrumada" de criar um descriptor dinamicamente - o que importa é que ele existe como um atributo de classe.

Então, mesmo que fosse possível alterar o `fget` de um objeto property (e não é - ele existe como um atributo "read only" no objeto), se você fizesse isso na classe filha, iria alterar o property na classe pai - é o mesmo objeto - e o comportamento seria alterado para todas as instâncias tanto da classe pai, quanto do filho, quanto de outras subclasses do pai.

**1ª forma - Modificando properties na herança - hard-coding os getters e setters**

Talvez a forma mais simples de alterar um property com herança seja simplesmente criar um novo property, zerado - vai ficar sendo um atributo de classe separado e independente na classe filha.

Da forma como você está fazendo, tem a vantagem de que os seus métodos getter e setter serem métodos "normaizinhos". (Se você usar o property na forma de decorator, esses métodos ficam "escondidos" e você não poderia usa-los).

O problema é que você não pode simplesmente colocar uma linha do tipo:

```
 name = property(fget=get_name, fset=set_name)
```

No corpo da classe filha se o `get_name` não está definido na classe filha também. E como você percebeu, não é possível chamar `super()` no nome da classe.
Isso aqui  funcionaria - o Python vai se achar e criar a property:

```
class Employee(Person):
     ...
     def set_name(self, value):
         ...

     name = property(fget=Person.get_name, fset=set_name)
```

Em Python 3, métodos normais (que são usados na instância), são funções sem qualquer coisa de especial quando recuperados como atributos de classe. O "property" por outro lado quer exatamente isso como parâmetros: funções normais - ele vai se encarregar de inserir o parâmetro`self` quando essas funções forem chamadas.

A única desvantagem desse método é que você é obrigado a colocar de forma fixa o nome da classe onde está o getter original - se estiver usando uma arquitetura com herança múltipla, pode ter problemas aí.

**2ª forma - Modificando properties na herança - `__init_subclass__`**

Uma forma mais elegante talvez seja usar essa funcionalidade introduzida no Python 3.6: uma classe ao ser herdada, vai ter o método `__init_subclass__` chamado com a classe recém-criada como parâmetro.  Esse método especial é um método de classe que só é chamado uma vez pra cada nova classe herdada.

Então é possível *Recriar* o property dentro do método `__init_subclass__` - nesse caso, as regras normais de acesso de atributo de classe vão achar os métodos desejados para seu getter e setter - e você não precisa se preocupar em marca-los explícitamente como parte de um property em cada nova classe criada.

Sua classe raiz ficaria assim:

class Person(...):

```
@abstractmethod
def __init__(self, name, telephone):
    self.name = name
    self.telephone = telephone

def __init_subclass__(cls, **kw):
    cls.name = property(cls.get_name, cls.set_name)
    super().__init_subclass__(**kw)

def get_name(self) -> str:
    return self._name

def set_name(self, value: str):
    self._name = value

name = property(fget=get_name, fset=set_name)
```

E aí, qualquer classe filha que fizer override seja do `get_name` seja do `set_name` vai ter uma nova propriedade e as regras de override vão funcionar normalmente para acesso ao property `name` - ele vai ser recriado com o método visível naquela classe descendente.

Comment: No caso da 2ª Forma, para fazer o override do `get_name` ou um `set_name` na classe filha, bastaria então recriar a função sem a necessidade de explicitar a criação da nova propriedade? Ou seja, na classe filha não seria mais necessária a linha `name = property(fget=Person.get_name, fset=set_name)`, bastaria recriar a função `set_nome`.

Comment: Exatamante - a função `__init_subclass__` vai ser chamada automaticamente pela linguagem, e vai receber a classe filha como parâmetro. Ao fazer referência a `cls.get_name`, os mecanismos normais de acesso a atributos com herança vão se aplicar, e os métodos mais derivados, mesmo numa hierarquia complicada, serão usados automaticamente.

Comment: Olá João. Desculpe pela demora no feedback. Realizei um teste seguindo as instruções que você deixou na **_"2ª Forma"_**.
O primeiro erro que tive foi que `super().__init_subclass()` não recebe argumentos. E confirmei isso na [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__). Por isso estou tendo o erro _"TypeError: __init_subclass__() takes no arguments (1 given)"_, tentei seguir o exemplo da doc `super().__init_subclass__(**kw)`, nesse caso não tenho erro mas a função não é sobrescrita. Segue o [código](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DrS4y5MDPY/)

Comment: Encontrai o problema. É que na inicialização do meu objeto, ou seja, no `__init__` a atribuição não esta passando pela proprerty. Para que isso aconteça basta alterar a primeira linha do `__init__` de `Person` de `self._name = name` para `self.name = name`.
Com relação a função `super().__init_subclass__`, realmente ela não recebe argumentos.

Comment: Ah sim - de fato, tinha um `cls` sobrando na chamada ao `super()` de  `__init_subclass__`. Ele é adicionado automaticamente pelo `super()`.