# Python erro com orientação a objetos

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

```
class DBAction(object):
    __conn = None
    __cursor = None
    __id = None

    def __init__(self, arg):        
        self.__id = arg
        self.__conn = sqlite3.connect('clientes.db')
        self.__cursor = conn.cursor()   

    def insert(self):
        sql = ''' INSERT INTO history(id,conversation)
              VALUES(?,?) '''       
        self.__cursor.execute(sql, self.__id, "user : "+srt(self.__id))
        self.__conn.commit()


    def verify(self):                   
        self.__cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM history WHERE id = '"+self.__id+"'")    
        rows = cur.fetchall()    
        for row in rows:
            print(row)
```

A classe acima esta retornando o erro:

```
self.__cursor.execute(sql, self.__id, "user : "+srt(self.__id))
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

E não estou entendendo o porque, alguém sabe me dizer o motivo? Sou novato em POO em python

Comment: eviye usar nomes com prefixo de dois underscores `__`  - esse uso não é para "atributos privados" - qualquer texto que você tenha dizendo isso está datado, e foi escrito por uma impressão errônea da linguagem na década passada. Na pratica, só vai te dar dor de cabeça.

Comment: Eu falo mais detalhadamente sobre esse uso do `__` numa parte desta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/351309/sobrescrever-property-na-classe-filha/352209#352209

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não seria porque você está iniciando self.__cursor com um valor não definido?
De onde vem esse conn? Não seria self.__conn?

```
def __init__(self, arg):        
    self.__id = arg
    self.__conn = sqlite3.connect('clientes.db')
    self.__cursor = self.__conn.cursor()
```

Comment: Valeu, foi falta de atenção da minha parte ;-;